# PiVPN (wireguard) and Eero

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, spectrum, wireguard

My current setup is modem > spectrum router > Eero

I am trying to setup PiVPN (wireguard) on my Raspberry Pi but it doesn't seem like I am able to connect to my Pi when I set up the vpn. I set a static ip for my Pi (on Eero) and set up port forwarding for the VPN - Port 51820/UDP with the IP Address of my Pi. I wonder if the issue is my spectrum router? Could it be blocking access to my VPN?

Thanks!